# Sound Blaster Recon3Di sound card not working with Ubuntu 16

Tags: sound, headphones

I have an Alienware 17 R2 with a Sound Blaster Recon3Di sound card. I installed Ubuntu as dual boot with Windows and everything works fine except for my headphone jacks.

It seems like Ubuntu does not detect my sound card at all. When I went into `alsamixer` in the terminal, it only detected the Intel HDMI and PCH sound cards, according to the list.

edit: Incorrect ubuntu version... oops. I am completely new to linx in general and am trying to switch due to school assignments. I have the most current version of the long support one 16.something.

Comment: Any Ubuntu "15" (15.40 or 15.10) is unsupported. Please install and use at all times a supported release, 16.04 LTS or the current 17.10.  It may be enough to support your hardware out of the box.

Comment: Typo above: Where it reads "15.40" it should be "15.04", obviously.

Comment: @philip the long term support version is 16.04.

Comment: use `lsb_release -a` to report your Ubuntu version. While you are at it use `uname -r` and report your kernel version too.

Answer (score 0):

alsamixer normally defaults the headphone jack to mute.... just unmute it using alsamixer